# Pythonnet (clr) and C# lists and enums

Tags: c#, clr, python.net

I have `myClass` which contains a field `myList` which is a list of elements from `myEnum`. I would like to add to this list more elements but in python. However `exec(f"myClass.myList.Add(myEnum.{e}))"` doesnt work because `myClass.myList` in Python is a list of integers. What can I do? I want to add elements by its name, not its int position.

Comment: i dunno if i understant, because its not very clear... but you cant modify an enum list dynamically..

Comment: I dont want to codify enum, but list of enums. How can I add new element to existing list in pythonnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to pythonnet 3.0 previews. In 3.0 .NET lists are not converted to Python lists, instead they just behave like Python lists when seen from Python.